# Bluetooth serial port profile communication streaming

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I would like to stream video from ine device to another via bluetooth.
My device does not support Video Distribution Profile (VDP) so I can only use SPP.
can it be done?
Thanks,
NinjAndroid
MoMinis R&D team

Answer (score 2):

The Serial Port Profile (and Bluetooth in general) is not fast enough to stream video data of appreciable resolution or quality.